# "Do not allow clipboard redirection" feature in Local group policy editor in windows 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have enabled "Do not allow clipboard redirection" feature in Local group policy editor in windows 2008, But still I am able to copy the files from remote desktop to my local system.

What should I do to disable the copy/cut in remote desktop, so that the logged user could not copy the files from remote to his/her system.

Please provide me the solution, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the GPO in the following directory?: Computer Configuration - Policies - Administrative Templates - Windows Components - Remote Desktop Services

Comment: I am using like Local Computer Policy->Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates-> Windows Components->Terminal Services->Terminal Server->Device and Resource Redirection........Is this the way to follow if not correct me.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this seems to have been provided at the link below.
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/992014-do-not-allow-clipboard-redirection

The upshot is that you need to disable the RDP clipboard from the client side as well (I personally don't understand what the server-side setting is for then...).
Here is the official doc describing this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/desktop/termserv/disabling-terminal-services-features

These sources say to set a DWORD with value 1 on this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server\DisableClipboardRedirection
```